# Changing DB in cursor does not persist

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor

My SQL :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @dbs CURSOR 
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @results TABLE (Name VARCHAR(MAX), Type VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @dbs = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

-- go through each db
OPEN @dbs
FETCH NEXT FROM @dbs INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'Use [' + @name + ']; PRINT DB_NAME();'
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql

    -- execute a query in the current db
    SELECT @type = ...; -- get a scalar value
    PRINT DB_NAME();

    -- insert the result into a list which is built up gradually
    insert into @results (Name, Type) VALUES (@name, @type)
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @dbs INTO @name
END

CLOSE @dbs
DEALLOCATE @dbs

-- send back the list which got its results from all dbs
SELECT Name, Type FROM @results
```

The first and the second `PRINT DB_NAME();` print different names, why?

Sample messages (new lines added for clarity):

```
DB1
DB0

DB2
DB0

DB3
DB0

DB0
DB0

DB4
DB0
```

`DB0` is the currently selected DB in the SSMS dropdown

Comment: It might help if your code was documented or you at least explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott commented.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the (officially undocumented) `sp_MSforeachdb` stored procedure, which executes a given query in each database - for which there are plenty of (unofficial) guides to usage found by a quick search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not caused be the cursor but te designed behavior of [sp_sqlexec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms188001.aspx).
`Changes in database context last only to the end of the sp_executesql statement.`
The same can be found for [EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms188332.aspx)
`Changes in database context last only until the end of the EXECUTE statement`

Comment: Any way to make it persist?

Comment: I don't think so, you might get your results direct from the `exec sp_sqlexec` like e.g.: `Declare @Outtab Table (Name varchar(50), Type varchar(50))    
SET @sql = 'Use [' + @name + ']; PRINT DB_NAME(); Select a,b from aTable'
Insert into @Outtab exec sp_sqlexec @sql` an work with your @Outtab